# Pushing two HTTP responses into one array

Tags: angular, typescript

When my view is initalized 2 HTTP requests are made and the data is saved to two different arrays. I don't want to have two for loops in my html to pull info from both. My question is how can I have push returned information to just one array? Is that possible? Would I have to use localstorage? (The keys in the interface and the keys returned in the json response are named exactly the same).

I need to save id, group, preset in the first response, and colorCode, colorGrade, colorType in the second (I've left comments in each of the subscribes below)

```
info: infoInterface[];
info2: infoInterface[];

ngOnInit() {

  this.getInfo.getPCode()
    .subscribe(
      (dieInfo: DieInfoInterface[]) => this.dieInfo = dieInfo,
      // On response I need to store id, group, preset 
      (error: Response) => console.log(error)
    );

  this.getInfo.getCCodes()
    .subscribe(
      (dieInfo2: DieInfoInterface[]) => {
      // on response I need to store colorCode, colorGrade, colorType
        this.dieInfo2 = dieInfo2

      },
      (error: Response) => console.log(error)
    );
}
```

getInfo service

```
getPCode(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get('')
    .map(
      (response: Response) => {
        return response.json().inform;
      }
    );
}

getCCodes(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get('')
    .map(
      (response: Response) => {
        return response.json().inform;
      }
    );
}
```

The interface

```
export interface infoInterface {

  id: number;
  group: any;
  colorCode: string;
  colorGrade: any;
  colorType: string;
  preset: string;
}
```

How I'm displaying the data. Currently I'm displaying data from `info[]` because I dont want two for loops

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let i of info">
  <div class="info col-sm-3">
    <div class="row">
      <h1>Die: </h1>
      <p> {{ info.id }} </p>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <h1>Color Code: </h1>
      <p> {{ info.group }} </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is not a good practice. single call will be triggred for a same request

Comment: What do you mean? How should I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Combine latest will give you the two latest items from your streams once they've both emitted.

```
this.getInfo.getPCode()
  .combineLatest(this.getInfo.getCCodes())
  .subscribe(([pcodes, ccodes]) => {
     const allcodes = pcodes.map((el, i) => {
        return { ...el, ...ccodes[i] };
     });
  });
```

Comment: I'm getting an error `Error:(38, 8) TS2339:Property 'combineLatest' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'.`

Comment: @ghan what build system are you using (Angular CLI? Webpack? System.js?) Try adding `import 'rxjs/rx';` to the top of your file.

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer should work, but since you are getting that combineLatest does not exist error I would imagine you are missing your import statement

```
  import 'rxjs/add/observable/combineLatest';
```

Comment: I just added the import but it still doesn't work. The full error is `TS2339:Property 'combineLatest' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'.` I've tried changing `<any>` to `<string>` and it still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

The RxJs answers are probably better and more elegant, but the below will work too, no need for local storage.

```js
info: infoInterface[] = [];

ngOnInit() {

  this.getInfo.getPCode()
    .subscribe(
      (dieInfo: DieInfoInterface[]) => this.info = this.info.concat(dieInfo),
      // On response I need to store id, group, preset 
      (error: Response) => console.log(error)
    );

  this.getInfo.getCCodes()
    .subscribe(
      (dieInfo2: DieInfoInterface[]) => {
      // on response I need to store colorCode, colorGrade, colorType
        this.info = this.info.concat(dieInfo2)

      },
      (error: Response) => console.log(error)
    );
}
```